# How Can I Efficiently Create Pandas DataFrame from Uneven Text Lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data collected over a loop that results in some text organized as lists.

In the example below, the string of `out1[0]` is related to the many strings in `out2[0]` and the string in `out1[1]` is related to the single string in `out2[1]`.

I'd like to create a dataframe that is organized like the one I created manually below from some arbitrary number of counts in each list (i.e., out1 could have K statements and the number of statements in out2 could also be arbitrary.)

```
out1 = ["I'm happy", 'This is crazy']
out2 = [["Im learning to be happy", "I'm troubled"], ["This is making me unhappy"]]
pd.DataFrame({'A': out1, 'B': ["Im learning to be happy", "This is making me unhappy"], 'C':["I'm troubled", "--"] })
```

Can anyone suggest a good way to produce such a dataframe in Pandas? Also, the '--' at the end is just a filler I created to mean nothing, so this should be an empty cell since this is essentially a ragged array of text data.

Answer (score 0):

You can first create an empty dictionary and then iterate over the elements of out1 and out2 to populate the dictionary. You can then create the dataframe from the dictionary.

This should get you started

```
import pandas as pd

out1 = ["I'm happy", 'This is crazy']
out2 = [["Im learning to be happy", "I'm troubled"], ["This is making me unhappy"]]

# create an empty dictionary to store the data
data = {'A': [], 'B': [], 'C': []}

# iterate over the elements of out1 and out2 and populate the dictionary
for i in range(len(out1)):
    data['A'].append(out1[i])
    for j in range(len(out2[i])):
        if j == 0:
            data['B'].append(out2[i][j])
        else:
            data['C'].append(out2[i][j])

# create the dataframe from the dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This is the result

```
           A                     B             C
0  I'm happy  Im learning to be happy  I'm troubled
1  This is crazy  This is making me unhappy          ---
```